# How to create YML file in php?

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

I want to create a YML file using php and write text in it so that it can be used in symfony. But I didn't found any helping link or material from which I can start. Also is their any difference in YML and YAML file?

Comment: You can use the [Yaml component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/introduction.html) to dump arbitrary data structures to YAML like this: `$data = ...; Yaml::dump($data);`

Answer (score 3):

To use YAML files you need to download Yaml component from Symfony framework. For example by executing

`composer require symfony/yaml` or by downloading it from [github](https://github.com/symfony/yaml)

If you choose composer remember to include vendor/autoload.php into your project.

You can find a lot of information how to start with yaml on [Symfony Page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/introduction.html) that describes the component, including creation and manipulation of files.

Yml is just an extension for Yaml files.